# Initialize vector with some values

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a vector like this

```
vector<int> a = {2, 1, 10, 5};
```

but I am getting an error from [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools)

> initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type
> "std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator>"

(using VSCode, macOS currently)

My code compiles without any error though.

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11` or greater?

Comment: I am on clang 12, c++11,14,17 are supported I guess then? @M.A

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVARSHNEY -- Advice -- know the tools you are using to build your C++ application -- compiler, what version of C++ standard is supported, linker, etc.  The code you posted is compliant with C++11 or greater, and not C++03 or C++98.

Comment: Can you copy the command line you used to compile into the question?

Comment: "/Users/sid/Documents/greedy/" && g++ --std=c++17 coins.cpp -o minCoins && "/Users/sid/Documents/greedy/"coins
@M.A

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/439d9e38a36e7001).  Look at your command line carefully:  `--std=c++17`.  You have two hyphens before `std`.

Comment: Some part of the information you have provided is not consistent, the error message suggests that compiler does not recognise the initialiser list object, and is therefore unable to constructing the vector.

Comment: This is not the error thrown by compiler.My code compiles without any error. I just updated the my question. Sorry for the confusion.